# pdf file upload ajax html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdf

```
    var file = $('#image').prop('files')[0];
    var filename = $('#af_rpta_propertyland_filename').val();

    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('file', file);
    alert(form_data);


    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../include/upload.php',
        //dataType: "json",
        data: {
            file: form_data,
            filename: filename
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                console.log("file " + i + ": " + data[i].file);
            }

        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert('No Record Found: ' + data);
        }


    });
```

`<input id="image" name="image" type="file" />`

This how i upload my pdf file using ajax in my php code i do it like this

```
$file = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['file']);
$filename = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['filename']);
    if (isset($_FILES['file']) && $_FILES['file']['size'] > 0) { 
                $tmpName  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];  
                $filetype = $_FILES['file']['type'];
                $fp = fopen($tmpName, 'rb'); // read binary
    $upload[] = array('filename' => $filename,'file' => $fp);

    }

echo json_encode($upload, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

From my `input(type file)` how can i place the `value(the pdf file)` in to `data(in ajax)` and from `data(ajax)` how can i pass it to php file so that i can check if the `$_files` is not empty

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try creating a `json` object from `files[0]` properties , converting `file` to `base64` string

js

```
$("#image").on("change", function(e) {
  var name = $("#af_rpta_propertyland_filename").val()
  , file = e.target.files[0]
  , filename = name.length > 1 ? name + ".pdf" : file.name
  , filetype = file.type
  , filesize = file.size
  , data = {
      "filename":filename,
      "filetype":filetype,
      "filesize":filesize
    }
  , reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      data.file_base64 = e.target.result.split(/,/)[1];
        $.post("fileupload.php", {file:data}, "json")
        .then(function(data) {
          // parse `json` string `data`
          var filedata = JSON.parse(data)
          // do stuff with `data` (`file`) object
          , results = $("<a />", {
                "href": "data:" + filedata.filetype 
                        + ";base64," + filedata.file_base64,
                "download": filedata.filename,
                "target": "_blank",
                "text": filedata.filename
              });
          $("body").append("<br>download:", results[0]);
        }, function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log(textStatus, errorThrown)
        })
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
});
```

php

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST["file"])) {
    // do php stuff
    // call `json_encode` on `file` object
    $file = json_encode($_POST["file"]);
    // return `file` as `json` string
    echo $file;
};
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/LL95z474/

Comment: I've seen the fiddle and it is working although this is a bit complicated for me i will study it and hope i will understand it please bare with me if i have question.

Comment: In name.length > 1 ? name + ".pdf" : file.name can i change ".pdf" to file.type if i want my code to be flexible?and one more thing $file will be the one that i will save in database right?and how to put the action on button click?

Comment: I cant understand the code i copy paste the code and i still get the error ` http://localhost/echo/json/ 404 (Not Found)` also how to make it in a way it will go from button click?

Comment: instead of `$("#image").on("change", function(e) {` i want on button click i wanted to change it but i am having error in the funtion(e) `file = e.target.files[0]` i tried it like this `$('idofinput').files[0]` but i got some error im not sure where. when i post the data in the php i can retrieve it by `$_POST["file"]` in the php file?

Comment: i always  get `Cannot read property '0' of undefined` when i change `var file = e.target.files[0];` to `var file = $('#image').files[0];`

Comment: @HogRider Try `$('#image')[0].files[0]` . `/echo/json/` used as `url` at jsfiddle to echo requests ; see http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html . Try creating a `php` file ; using created file name as `$.post`  `url` . Try http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/LL95z474/4/

Comment: im sorry i think we didnt understand each other what i mean by firing on button click is instead of on change i want on button click..Or it is not possible?when i choose a file to upload i will click a button then the download link will appear.the first one should do it but i need a button when i click the button it will show the link

Comment: i have an idea what if i remove the onchange event of image and it will only happened if i click the button what do you is this possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70199/discussion-between-hogrider-and-guest271314).

Comment: sir i was able to send it to php now do i need to change the type of data?or just save it as blob?

Comment: Not certain which format is required for further processing ? Could save `$file` as `json` object , or `base64` string from `data.file_base64` ?

Comment: i want to save the file as blob..so i need to use `data.file_base64` for that or is it ok to use the `var file` or the `var data`?which of these is the one that i will save in database?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Comment: last question sir how to convert this one to accept multiple upload?

Comment: Add `multiple=true` to `input` element attributes , see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

Answer (score 6):

**Use jQuery version "jquery-1.10.2.min.js"**

Use this AJAX

```
$.ajax({
        url: "YourPage.php", 
        type: "POST",             
        data: new FormData('YourFormId'), 
        contentType: false,                  
        processData:false,        
        success: function(data)   
        {
            // Do your Stuff
        }
    });
```

At PHP page just simply use this line

```
$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
```

In this code i have used **two new events**

1. **contentType**
2. **processData**

This is necessary to use these to upload and access all data in AJAX.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: **new FormData('YourFormId')**  is also important