# .pdf/mp4 upload from JQuery-AJAX to MVC controller method

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I am trying to send .pdf/.mp4 file to mvc controller from JQuery-AJAX. Here is my code-

```
    //JQuery-AJAX
    $('#fileUpload').change(function (e) {
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    fd.append("photos",  file);
    fd.append("CourseId", courseid);
    fd.append("LessonId", lessonid);      
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Admin/Course/SaveFile',
        type: 'POST',
        data: fd,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: handler,
        error: handler
     });
 });

  //server-side
  public JsonResult SaveFile(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> photos, FormCollection data)
  {
     var courseId = data["CourseId"].ToString());
     .....
     foreach (var file in photos)
     {
        file.SaveAs(somePath);
     }
     ....
  }
```

But the request is not going to the controller method if `contentType: false`.

When `contentType: "multipart/form-data"`, then it hits controller method but `data["CourseId"]` throws exception `object reference not set ...`

But I'm using the same code to upload images nicely.

Any help?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207106/pdf-file-upload-ajax-html/28257733#28257733

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding those lines in web.config solved my problem-

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
       <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```