# Empty FormData in POST Request

Tags: javascript, post, xmlhttprequest, form-data

I'm making a simple application that will upload a file a server that has been dragged and dropped onto a canvas.

Here's a small sample of what the drag and drop code looks like:

```
var files = event.dataTransfer.files;
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('files', files);
```

Using the debug tools, I know that `files` is correctly defined.

Then, I make the request:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/upload', true);
xhr.send(formData);
```

But my server, running Node JS, gets an empty response body:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.files);
    res.end();
});
```

I tried debugging on both the client and server side, but I can't figure it out. Although, it seems weird to me that the `formData` object looks like:

```
FormData {append: function}
    __proto__: FormData
```

Why isn't the appended `files` object showing up?

Any insight as to what the problem is would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you should also pass the filename for better backend compat...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After too long of a time working on this problem, I finally figured it out. The issue was server-side; my Express application was ignoring the body of the post since I have not *explicitly* set the `bodyParser` to accept JSON.

The Express setup for a POST method should be:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // Configures bodyParser to accept JSON
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
```

With a sample routing method like:

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.files);
    res.end();
});
```

It also is helpful to know that this server side setup can be tested by running something like this:

```
curl -d '{"file":{"name":"sample"}}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8080/upload
```

Comment: Setting the body to be explicitly JSON will not handle real files correctly. It is possible that you can use body-parser and another middleware to handle multipart/form-data encoding, such as Multer.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
var files = event.dataTransfer.files;
```

to

```
var files = event.dataTransfer.files[0];
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects ; see also [node-form-data](https://github.com/felixge/node-form-data)

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. The response body is still blank and `formData` still looks like an empty object. I might look into the Node library you linked. Right now I was going for a pure Javascript solution, but since I'm using Express with EJS, it's a possibility.

Comment: Tried utilizing `json` , `data-uri` instead of `formData` object ?

Comment: I tried just passing in the JSON, and that didn't work either: `xhr.send(JSON.stringify(files));`

Comment: @JamesTaylor See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207106/pdf-file-upload-ajax-html/ for single file , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856729/upload-multiple-image-using-ajax-php-and-jquery/ for multiples files, including `event.dataTransfer.files[0]`  . Single file example perhaps simpler to read portions where file is converted to `data URI` , `base64` string ; `json` including file name, file size, file type. Could include js approach at post above if jquery usage at links not able to be included at implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'm using JS as opposed to PHP. I'm not sure if the approach would be the same or not, but I'll explore it.

Comment: @JamesTaylor `POST` to server should be `json` data format; could utilize `JSON.parse` , `JSON.stringify` to process `POST` , serve response ?