# File Upload MVC and AJAX - Custom File Properties

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to upload files in MVC5, using AJAX. I am wondering if there is a way that I can add a custom property to the files in JavaScript and have it accessible in C#

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" id="file1">
<input type="file" id="file2">
<input type="file" id="file3">
```

**JavaScript**

```
var formData = new FormData();
var file1 = $('#file1')[0].files[0];
var file2 = $('#file2')[0].files[0];
var file3 = $('#file3')[0].files[0];

file1.Category = "1";
file2.Category = "1";
file3.Category = "2";

formData.append(file1.name, file1)
formData.append(file2.name, file2)
formData.append(file3.name, file3)

$.ajax({
       url: 'UploadFiles'
       type: 'POST',
       data: formData,
       cache: false,
       contentType: false,
       processData: false
       });
```

**C#**

```
public ActionResult UploadFiles()
    {
        var files = Request.Files;
        //Can I get Request.Files[0].Category?
        SaveFiles(Request.Files);
        return View();
    }
```

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: HTTP does not support that at all.

Comment: Thanks, I thought not, but wanted to check.

Comment: Try utilizing `json` object instead of `formData` to upload files ; add properties to `json` object http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207106/pdf-file-upload-ajax-html/