# Direct use of formData (json file import/upload)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The file upload to my server works well, but is it possible to use the (json) form data direct?

Form upload:

```
 <form id="file-form" action="" method="POST">
      <input type="file" id="file-select" name="file" />
      <button type="submit" id="upload-button">Upload_Test</button>
 </form>

 var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
 alert(formData);
```

I want to use the file-data (json file) direct. `JSON.stringify(formData);` is empty.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207106/pdf-file-upload-ajax-html/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't convert a FormData object directly to JSON. The browser doesn't know how to do it.

There is also no standard way to represent an arbitrary file in JSON.

You would need to build up a standard JavaScript object yourself, by looping over the form controls, being smart about how you handle selects, checkboxes and radio buttons and then using [the file API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) to read the data from the file input.

Once you have the data from the file input, you need a way to express it as a basic JavaScript data type. If it is text you can just use it as a string. If it is a binary then you'll have to find a way to express it. Converting it to a base64 string is one option.